# wpf TextBox TexPreviewTextInput not working with binding

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I'm trying to catch TexPreviewTextInput event from TextBox on binding change and it doesn't work.
I want to be able to get the current value and the new value, I'm not changing some of the charterers, but the whole string with binding.

```
<TextBox x:Name="TB" Text="{Binding TBText}" PreviewTextInput="Sender_TexPreviewTextInput"/>
```

and the code behind is:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TB.Text = "First Value";
        Loaded+=MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    public string  TBText { get; set; }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TB.Text = "Changed Value";
    }

    void Sender_TexPreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do Somthing
    }
```

Comment: Could u be more specific what u are doing or want to do in this event ? U are also setting values 2 times ... `TBText` and `TB.Text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PreviewTextInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewtextinput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event is raised whenever ***user input text via device*** (keyboard mostly).

If you are interested in whenever text changed from code behind or via binding or via device input, hook to [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
With TextChanged event I can only see the new value, not the old one.
TextChanged event have Changes property, but is show the changes on the original text, and I override the whole of it.

Comment: How about having a backup field of string in your class to store old Text and update it whenever `TextChanged` event raises?

Comment: I need this logic for a TextBox that is in template.
I don't want to save the original value for any TextBox event if it hasn't changed. I want to save those changes only for changes.